# Changing QTreeView text color in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I use QTreeView for my model. QTreeView style described by CSS (gray background and white text). I implemented search on the tree and applied for found rows another color (yellow background and black text). For this i reimplement drawRow() function:

```
void MyTreeView:drawRow(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& options, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  QStyleOptionViewItem newOption(options);

  if (m_findedIndexes.contains(index))
  {
    newOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor(0, 0, 0));
    painter->fillRect(newOption.rect, Qt::yellow);
  }
  QTreeView::drawRow(painter, newOption, index);
}
```

In Qt 4.7.1 everything worked correctly. I switched to Qt 5.4.0 and faced with adversity. Background color not changed (yellow) but text color stays white (in the CSS). Black color for text not apply. I don't understand why this happen. May be in QT 5.4.0 CSS style has above priority than QStyleOptionViewItem? How can i change text color?

P.S. I'm tried to use QStyledItemDelegate and i tried to return text color from my model (flag Qt::ForegroundRole). No results.

Comment: I think the right way to color text and background is using `Qt::BackgroundRole` and `Qt::ForegroundRole` in your tree view model's data() function.

Comment: I tried it. In Qt 4.7.1 this variant worked despite of CSS. In Qt 5.4.0 this variant not work due to CSS. CSS override colors which return data() function.

Comment: Problem must be somewhere else. Your code works for me. Stylesheet: **"color: white; background-color: blue"** and no changes in drawRow: white font + blue background. If I activate **newOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor(255, 0, 0));
  painter->fillRect(newOption.rect, Qt::green);** font red, background green. Despite stylesheet. But I am using Qt5.5 beta